# Export Data to Excel from Oracle Forms 12c Using Client_OLE2

Tags: excel, oracle, oracleforms

Please help me with share sample procedure to export data to excel from oracle forms using client_ole2.

Comment: Which operating system is your application server ?

Comment: Hi, Sorry for late reply, Windows Operating System exists in application server

Answer (score 1):

Then this should work:

```
declare
   source_cursor    Integer;
   l_colCnt         Number            Default 0;
   l_descTbl        Dbms_sql.desc_tab;
   newval1          Varchar2 (4000);
   application      CLIENT_OLE2.OBJ_TYPE;
   workbooks        CLIENT_OLE2.OBJ_TYPE;
   workbook         CLIENT_OLE2.OBJ_TYPE;
   worksheets       CLIENT_OLE2.OBJ_TYPE;
   worksheet        CLIENT_OLE2.OBJ_TYPE;
   colour           CLIENT_OLE2.OBJ_TYPE;
   cell             CLIENT_OLE2.OBJ_TYPE;
   RANGE            CLIENT_OLE2.OBJ_TYPE;
   range_col        CLIENT_OLE2.OBJ_TYPE;
   range_row        CLIENT_OLE2.OBJ_TYPE;
   args             CLIENT_OLE2.LIST_TYPE;
   rows_processed   Number;
   row_n            Number;
   VAL              Varchar2 (100);
   x                Number;
   filename         Varchar2 (200);
   csql varchar2(4000);
BEGIN
   csql := 'select column1, column2 from table1';
   BEGIN
      source_cursor := Dbms_Sql.open_Cursor;
      Dbms_Sql.parse (source_cursor, cSql, 2);
      Dbms_Sql.describe_Columns (c => source_cursor, col_cnt => l_colCnt, desc_t => l_descTbl);
   EXCEPTION
      When Others
      Then
         def_error (SQLERRM);
         RETURN;
   END;

   application := CLIENT_OLE2.CREATE_OBJ ('Excel.Application');
   CLIENT_OLE2.SET_PROPERTY (application, 'Visible', 'False');
   workbooks := CLIENT_OLE2.GET_OBJ_PROPERTY (application, 'Workbooks');
   workbook := CLIENT_OLE2.GET_OBJ_PROPERTY (workbooks, 'Add');
   worksheets := CLIENT_OLE2.GET_OBJ_PROPERTY (workbook, 'Worksheets');
   args := CLIENT_OLE2.CREATE_ARGLIST;
   CLIENT_OLE2.ADD_ARG (args, 1);
   worksheet := CLIENT_OLE2.GET_OBJ_PROPERTY (worksheets, 'Item', args);
   CLIENT_OLE2.DESTROY_ARGLIST (args);

   For T In 1 .. l_colCnt
   LOOP
      BEGIN
         Dbms_Sql.define_Column (source_cursor, T, newval1, 4000);
         args := CLIENT_OLE2.CREATE_ARGLIST;
         CLIENT_OLE2.ADD_ARG (args, 1);
         CLIENT_OLE2.ADD_ARG (args, T);                                                      --Next column
         cell := CLIENT_OLE2.GET_OBJ_PROPERTY (worksheet, 'Cells', args);
         CLIENT_OLE2.DESTROY_ARGLIST (args);
         colour := client_ole2.get_obj_property (cell, 'Borders');
         client_ole2.set_property (colour, 'ColorIndex', 1);
         client_ole2.Release_obj (colour);
         colour := client_ole2.get_obj_property (cell, 'Interior');
         client_ole2.set_property (colour, 'ColorIndex', 15);
         client_ole2.Release_obj (colour);
         CLIENT_OLE2.SET_PROPERTY (cell, 'Value', l_descTbl (T).col_name);
         CLIENT_OLE2.Release_obj (cell);
      EXCEPTION
         When Others
         Then
            Null;
      END;
   END LOOP;

   Rows_processed := Dbms_Sql.EXECUTE (source_cursor);
   row_n := 1;

   LOOP
      IF Dbms_Sql.fetch_Rows (source_cursor) > 0
      Then
         For T In 1 .. l_colCnt
         LOOP
            BEGIN
               Dbms_Sql.column_Value (source_cursor, T, newval1);
               args := CLIENT_OLE2.CREATE_ARGLIST;
               CLIENT_OLE2.ADD_ARG (args, row_n + 1);
               CLIENT_OLE2.ADD_ARG (args, T);                                                --Next column
               cell := CLIENT_OLE2.GET_OBJ_PROPERTY (worksheet, 'Cells', args);
               CLIENT_OLE2.DESTROY_ARGLIST (args);
               colour := client_ole2.get_obj_property (cell, 'Borders');
               client_ole2.set_property (colour, 'ColorIndex', 1);
               client_ole2.Release_obj (colour);
               CLIENT_OLE2.SET_PROPERTY (cell, 'Value', newval1);
               CLIENT_OLE2.Release_obj (cell);
            EXCEPTION
               When Others
               Then
                  EXIT;
            END;

            newval1 := Null;
         END LOOP;
      Else
         EXIT;
      END IF;

      row_n := row_n + 1;
   END LOOP;

   Dbms_Sql.close_Cursor (source_cursor);
   -- Autofit columns
   RANGE := CLIENT_OLE2.GET_OBJ_PROPERTY (worksheet, 'UsedRange');
   range_col := CLIENT_OLE2.GET_OBJ_PROPERTY (RANGE, 'Columns');
   range_row := CLIENT_OLE2.GET_OBJ_PROPERTY (RANGE, 'Rows');
   CLIENT_OLE2.INVOKE (range_col, 'AutoFit');
   CLIENT_OLE2.INVOKE (range_row, 'AutoFit');
   CLIENT_OLE2.Release_obj (RANGE);
   CLIENT_OLE2.Release_obj (range_col);
   CLIENT_OLE2.Release_obj (range_row);
   -- Get filename and path
   filename :=  'Yourexcel.xls';

   -- Save as worksheet
   IF Nvl (filename, '0') <> '0'
   Then
      CLIENT_OLE2.SET_PROPERTY (application, 'Visible', 'True');
      args := CLIENT_OLE2.CREATE_ARGLIST;
      CLIENT_OLE2.ADD_ARG (args, filename);
      CLIENT_OLE2.INVOKE (worksheet, 'SaveAs', args);
      CLIENT_OLE2.DESTROY_ARGLIST (args);
   END IF;

--  CLIENT_OLE2.INVOKE( workbook ,'Close');
   CLIENT_OLE2.Release_obj (worksheet);
   CLIENT_OLE2.Release_obj (worksheets);
   CLIENT_OLE2.Release_obj (workbook);
   CLIENT_OLE2.Release_obj (workbooks);
   CLIENT_OLE2.Release_obj (application);
END;
```